# How to update detached entities without providing all fields?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I want to update some entities without loading those into memory first. I know this should work:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity
{
    PkId = 123
};

myContext.Entry(myEntity).State = EntityState.Modified;
myEntity.ProcessTime = DateTime.Now;
myContext.SaveChanges();
```

But upon calling `SaveChanges` I am facing some `DbEntityValidationException` stating some fields are required. I worked with EF4 (`ObjectContext`), but this never happened. Also, it is stating only 3 required fields although there are 8+ required fields.

Tried this too before `SaveChanges` (no luck):

```
myContext.Entry(myEntity).Property(e=>e.ProcessTime).IsModified = true;
```

If I use `_context.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false;` then the `SaveChanges` does not throw exceptions, but worse; it updates the db-row with default clr values!

How can I do this?

I am using:

- EF 6.1.3 (Database First)
- Oracle Data Provider NET 12c Release 4
- Visual Studio 2012
- Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found this utterly disgusting (and wrong) way which worked:

```
var myEntity = new MyEntity
{
    PkId = 123
};

// If you skip this, the validation error occurs again.
// If you keep it, you might be killed.
myContext.Configuration.ValidateOnSaveEnabled = false; 

var dbEntry = myContext.Entry(myEntity);

// Let it think everything is just fine.
dbEntry.State = EntityState.UnChanged;

// If you have some fields already having updated value (before attaching),
// Inform it that it has been modified
// dbEntry.Property(r => r.YourProperty).IsModified = true;

// Change your field value.
// If you change a field, the state is already modified
// So, you don't need to tell it. Just change.
myEntity.ProcessTime = DateTime.Now;

// Call to save it and hope you did not forget to init any field value of any
// entity to be inserted in this context. If you did (mistakenly), it will remain
// silent and kill you later
myContext.SaveChanges();
```